# Windows Auto-Login not sticking

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, group-policy

I have a series of public PCs that are supposed to automatically log in to a specific user. I have set the required registry values (detailed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310584)) via a GPO from the library's main server. This is how they've been setup for ages, and this works for months at a time before something happens.

**The issue**: SOME of the PCs revert back to not logging in automatically every time. This issue doesn't show up on ALL of the PCs, and in fact it doesn't show up on the same PC every time. Some times it logs in like it's supposed to, and some times it doesn't.

Last time this happened I added two new rules to the GPO for `Computer/Admin Template/System/Group Policy/Startup policy processing wait time` set to 120 seconds and `Computer/Admin Template/System/Logon/Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon` set to Enabled. This same GPO also holds the Registry entries for auto logon as well.

Those rules were added 4-5 months ago, and things have been hunky-dory until yesterday when I got a notice saying some of the PCs are reverting back to the original issue.

My current guess is that some Windows Update or another is causing this behavior.

**EDIT**: I've gone through and removed the few WUs that were installed since the issue popped up again. No change in behavior.

I haven't found any source that would suggest this is a known bug, either. Any suggestions or recommendations are welcome.

Comment: If you suspect a Windows Update start to uninstall the most recent updates until the group policy is restored.  If its the same machines all the time, I suggest just applying your image again, to eliminate any possibilities of it returning

Comment: Just finished going through the WUs that have been installed since the issue popped up again, and the one PC is still not logging in reliably. Maybe 1 out of 3 reboots it won't log in.

GPO's settings aren't getting reverted, either. Looking at the registry, I can see the settings and they're correct.

Comment: I would just image that PC again and see if the problem still exists at that point.

Comment: If I can avoid it, I'd really rather not re-image those PCs. In the past: Just because the others have all rebooted properly a half dozen times doesn't necessarily mean the issue is gone. It's fickle. If you have any other alternatives apart from re-imaging, I'd love to hear 'em.

Comment: What happens when they don't automatically log in? Do you get prompted to log in or do you have to click the domain message "OK" button for it to continue the log in?

Comment: You're prompted for a password. The correct user name and domain are there, but the password needs to be entered manually.

Comment: The last user and domain name in win7 are different keys (HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\LastLoggedOnUser) than the autologin anyway so that is not much of an indication... Are the reg keys still present and it just doesn't log in anymore or are the keys somehow altered?

Comment: Keys are still present. As far as I can tell, all of the settings look correct even when the PC fails to log in properly.